# parsing xml in android that contains cdata as tag

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an XML file something like the following:

```
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://r16---sn-o097znl7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=36&expire=1415213271&requiressl=yes&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=e8gdyXXONR4&signature=7B6D037A1C22DBFB32744C8255BB84578FA32025.AD47E1B35C9BA4B427CB27FE2DBC8B5C68EEB18E&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1415191522&source=youtube&ip=216.12.194.2&initcwndbps=1583750&sver=3&key=yt5&id=o-AP0H2mfAbAl9n-uDZ0Xto3KC7qHeCFL1TC5_aLlW-odn&fexp=930666%2C932404%2C940240%2C947209%2C947215%2C948124%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C953912%2C957103%2C957201&ipbits=0&mm=31&ratebypass=yes
]]>
</link>
```

It contains a long URL and is using CDATA. The URL is showing up fine until here.

I am trying to parse it using XMLParser.
Using the following code:

```
static final String key_link="link";
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

// here URL is url to xml document 

String size=parser.getValue(e,key_link);
```

It is returning empty. When I replace the long link with some other text without CDATA I am able to read it. With CDATA I am not able to read the value into a string in the client.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: This problem comes in Action script 3 as well.

Comment: Nope. I googled a bit. But I could not get any solution. I manually removed the CDATA tags from the input for the purpose of testing.

Comment: i just tried to parse url replacing & with amp&; it does show the link in xml but while parsing its reading only till first appearence of & why it so any ideas or suggestions

Comment: what is the exact value of your URL ?

Comment: https://r16---sn-o097znl7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=36&expire=1415213271&requiressl=yes&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=e8gdyXXONR4&signature=7B6D037A1C22DBFB32744C8255BB84578FA32025.AD47E1B35C9BA4B427CB27FE2DBC8B5C68EEB18E&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1415191522&source=youtube&ip=216.12.194.2&initcwndbps=1583750&sver=3&key=yt5&id=o-AP0H2mfAbAl9n-uDZ0Xto3KC7qHeCFL1TC5_aLlW-odn&fexp=930666%2C932404%2C940240%2C947209%2C947215%2C948124%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C953912%2C957103%2C957201&ipbits=0&mm=31&ratebypass=yes